# Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Driver

Tags: java, intellij-idea, xsd, jaxb

I want to use IntelliJ tool and generate Java code from XML schema using JAXB but I'm encountering error problem mentioned above.

[JAXB tool window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut2UK.png)

This is my .xsd file i want to generate code from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:tns="http://localhost:9090/api/productions/list"
           targetNamespace="http://localhost:9090/api/productions/list"
>

    <xs:element name="getProduction">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="getResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="production" type="tns:production"/>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:complexType name="production">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>
            <xs:element name="guid" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm afraid running jxc from IntelliJ IDEA is not supported on JDK versions 9 and above. Please see [IDEA-179691](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-179691) and related issues for more information.

The "Generate Xml Schema from Java using JAXB" action should work with Java 8.